# Is there a direct way to scale down the font size on the authors of a tikzposter only?

Tags: posters, tikzposter

I have looked at [the documentation](http://ctan.mackichan.com/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzposter/tikzposter.pdf), but did not see an option to set the font size of the authors list without modifying the font size of anything else in the title block.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are 3 ways:

1) scale to a given letter height, using `\scaleto` from the `scalerel` package.

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\title{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering This is a really  really  really  really  really  really  really  really  really  long title for a poster}}
\institute{The Institute}
\author{\scaleto{$\vphantom{Xj}The Author$}{20pt}}
\titlegraphic{Logo}
\usetheme{Basic}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\block{BlocktitleA}{Blocktext}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.3}
\block{BlocktitleB}{Blocktext}
\column{0.7}
\block{BlocktitleC}{Blocktext}
\note{Notetext}
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

2) use LaTeX font size change, such as `\tiny`

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\title{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering This is a really  really  really  really  really  really  really  really  really  long title for a poster}}
\institute{The Institute}
\author{\tiny The Author}
\titlegraphic{Logo}
\usetheme{Basic}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\block{BlocktitleA}{Blocktext}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.3}
\block{BlocktitleB}{Blocktext}
\column{0.7}
\block{BlocktitleC}{Blocktext}
\note{Notetext}
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```

3) Scale the author block by a given ratio, using `\scalebox`

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}

\title{\parbox{\linewidth}{\centering This is a really  really  really  really  really  really  really  really  really  long title for a poster}}
\institute{The Institute}
\author{\scalebox{.2}{The Author}}
\titlegraphic{Logo}
\usetheme{Basic}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\block{BlocktitleA}{Blocktext}
\begin{columns}
\column{0.3}
\block{BlocktitleB}{Blocktext}
\column{0.7}
\block{BlocktitleC}{Blocktext}
\note{Notetext}
\end{columns}

\end{document}
```